# Scrolling backgrounds with map-based collision detection Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a game, that uses a map for collision, this all worked until I attempted to add scrolling to the game. It is supposed to make the background move instead of the player, which it does, but the problem lies within the collision detection.

The size of each collision point goes from 16 by 16, to 1 by 1.
This has proven to be quite problematic, and any help with fixing it will be greatly appreciated

I have tried changed to player's collision values, screen sizes, but in the end I am not sure what the exact cause of this problem is, my best guess would be that my removal of the player's movement and instead having it remain at the same position on the screen, has lead to problem with how the collision is suppose to act with the change in position, but this doesn't explain the shrinking of the collision points.

```
import pygame, sys

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init() # initiates pygame

pygame.display.set_caption('The Game')

WINDOW_SIZE = (600,400)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE,0,32)

display = pygame.Surface((300,200))

moving_right = False
moving_left = False
moving_up = False
moving_down = False

game_map = [['2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2'],
           ['2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2'],
           ['2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2'],
           ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
           ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
           ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
           ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
           ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
           ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
           ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
           ['2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2'],
           ['2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2'],
           ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0']]

player_rect = pygame.Rect(100,100,16,16)
black = (45,45,45)
black1 = (60,60,60)

def collision_test(rect,tiles):
   hit_list = []
   for tile in tiles:
       if rect.colliderect(tile):
           hit_list.append(tile)
   return hit_list

def move(rect,movement,tiles):
   collision_types = {'top':False,'bottom':False,'right':False,'left':False}
   rect.x += movement[0]
   hit_list = collision_test(rect,tiles)
   for tile in hit_list:
       if movement[0] > 0:
           rect.right = tile.left
           collision_types['right'] = True
       elif movement[0] < 0:
           rect.left = tile.right
           collision_types['left'] = True
   rect.y += movement[1]
   hit_list = collision_test(rect,tiles)
   for tile in hit_list:
       if movement[1] > 0:
           rect.bottom = tile.top
           collision_types['bottom'] = True
       elif movement[1] < 0:
           rect.top = tile.bottom
           collision_types['top'] = True
   return rect, collision_types

while True:
   display.fill((155,155,155))
   tile_rects = []
   y = 0
   for layer in game_map:
       x = 0
       for tile in layer: # tiles
           if tile == '2':
               pygame.draw.rect(display,black,(x*16-player_rect.x,y*16-player_rect.y,16,16))
           if tile != '0':
               tile_rects.append(pygame.Rect(x*16-player_rect.x,y*16-player_rect.y,16,16))
           x += 1
       y += 1

   player_movement = [0,0]
   if moving_right == True:
       player_movement[0] += 2
   if moving_left == True:
       player_movement[0] -= 2
   if moving_up == True:
       player_movement[1] -= 2
   if moving_down == True:
       player_movement[1] += 2
   player_rect,collisions = move(player_rect,player_movement,tile_rects)

   pygame.draw.rect(display,black1,(142,100,16,16)) #replacing the 142 and 100 with the rect.x and y, and remove the rect.x and y from the tiles, will make it work like the original


   for event in pygame.event.get(): # event loop
       if event.type == QUIT:
           pygame.quit()
           sys.exit()
       if event.type == KEYDOWN:
           if event.key == K_RIGHT:
               moving_right = True
           if event.key == K_LEFT:
               moving_left = True
           if event.key == K_UP:
               moving_up = True
           if event.key == K_DOWN:
               moving_down = True
       if event.type == KEYUP:
           if event.key == K_RIGHT:
               moving_right = False
           if event.key == K_LEFT:
               moving_left = False
           if event.key == K_UP:
               moving_up = False
           if event.key == K_DOWN:
               moving_down = False
   screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(display,WINDOW_SIZE),(0,0))
   pygame.display.update()
   clock.tick(60)
```

My expected result was for the collision points not to change and remain 16 by 16, unfortunately, instead the collision points for the tiles has shrank to 1 by 1, leading to many problems.

Comment: the problematic code is from what I can see with this line:

pygame.draw.rect(display,black,(x*16-player_rect.x,y*16-player_rect.y,16,16))

Comment: when it didn't have the player_rect.x the collision points worked and were 16 by 16

Comment: the player_rect.x is originally from the where the player is displayed, but I moved it and made the player stay in on spot

Comment: this is where the problems began

Comment: so the problems are I believe within the for loop that displays the tiles

Comment: Please, post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce your error.

Comment: okay I will do that.

Comment: I have edited the code in the question to include a shorten version of the game, that just includes the code relevant to the problem that I am having

Comment: I also made the player and tiles into just squares so that the image files are not required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is a bit hard to follow, but I've understood where the problem is.

In your `move` function you change the coordinates of `player_rect` to make it move. But then when you draw it (`pygame.draw.rect(display,black1,(142,100,16,16))`) you draw it at the center. So there is a mismatch between what you draw and what is tested for movement.

Honestly, I cannot find a way to solve it without changing a lot of code.
If you want to keep the backgroung scrolling, consider to not move the player but to move the tiles in the opposite direction. I mean, if the player goes left, move the tiles right, and so on.
Currently you are creating the tiles each iteration. I would recommend to create them outside the main loop, and in the loop move them (editing the coordinates of their `rect`s).